# regex backward find all text between a string and first occurrence of another string

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I need to find the most recent occurrence of 'GET' ( GET zzzz) before the 'error:' and capture all of the text in between.

```
GET xxxxx
GET yyyyy
GET zzzzz
Some text
more text
error: this is an error
```

Can this be done?

### edit

Thanks, the awk solution works, but can this be further improved by getting the LAST occurrence of 'error:' ?

```
GET xxxxx
GET yyyyy
GET zzzzz
Some text
more text
error: this is the first error

GET xxxxx
GET yyyyy
GET zzzzz
Some text
more text
error: this is the last error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following `awk` solution:

```
awk '
  /^GET/ { delete lines; c=0; inBlock=1 }
  /^error:/ { for(i=1; i<=c; ++i) print lines[i]; print; exit }
  inBlock { lines[++c] = $0 }
' file
```

This assumes that only *1* block must be printed, and that the `error:` line should also be printed. (Update: see below for a solution that prints only the *last* block).

- `/^GET/ { delete lines; c=0; inBlock=1 }` starts building up an array of lines in variable `lines` whenever string `GET` is encountered at the start of a line.
- `/^error:/ { for(i=1; i<=c; ++i) print lines[i]; print; exit }` matches string `error:` at the start of the line and prints out all lines built up so far, followed by the current line, and then exits.
- `inBlock { lines[++c] = $0 }` adds every line starting with the most recent `GET` line to the array.

---

**Update**, per the OP's request:

To report (only) the *last* block that ends with `error:`, use the following:

```
awk '
  /^GET/ { delete lines; c=0; inBlock=1 }
  inBlock { lines[++c] = $0 }
  /^error:/ { inBlock=0; }
  END { for(i=1; i<=c; ++i) print lines[i] }
' file
```

This differs from the first solution in that later blocks simply replace earlier ones, so that the last block "wins", which is then printed after all input has been processed, in the `END` block of the Awk script.

Comment: Thanks so much, I tried this but it only appears to return the last line containing the 'error:...'

Comment: With your sample input I get the desired range of lines with BSD awk, GNU awk, and mawk. If you don't, let us know what `awk` implementation you're using. If your sample input isn't truly representative of your actual input, please update it.

Comment: How could it be modified to get the LAST occurence of error ?

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much that works great. Actual application is parsing las error from log file after engine restarts

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ echo "$tgt"
first line
second line
GET xxxxx
GET yyyyy
GET zzzzz
Some text
more text
error: this is the first error

GET xxxxx
GET yyyyy
GET zzzzzLAST
Some text
more text
error: this is the last error
last line
```

You can have a multiline regex that will discard all characters until the last desired block like so:

```
/^.*^(GET.*^error[^\n]*)/ms
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lX8xW2/2)

Now with with Perl, read the entire file and match against that. The `-0777` command line option will cause the entire file to be read:

```
$ echo "$tgt" | perl -0777 -ne 'print $1 if m/^.*^(GET.*^error[^\n]*)/sm'
GET zzzzzLAST
Some text
more text
error: this is the last error
```

If you want to include the lines beyond the last 'error' line, change the regex to:

```
/\A.*^(GET.*^error.*)\Z/ms
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lX8xW2/3)

In Perl:

```
$ echo "$tgt" | perl -0777 -ne 'print $1 if m/\A.*^(GET.*^error.*)\Z/ms'
GET zzzzzLAST
Some text
more text
error: this is the last error
last line
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to get desired result with following regexp:

```
(GET[^\n]+\n(?!GET).*)error:
```

You can test it on http://regexpal.com/ in ". matches all" mode.

Comment: Note the `bash` tag in the question. What tool do you expect the OP to use here?